# Hive Query Error - While copy existing table data to another table

Tags: hive

I have loaded a web file to a table using serde in hive. i am able to view the table data. now i want to copy the data to a new table. If i run a new table

`-Create table new_xxx as select * from XXX`; 
 - the job is failing.

Error in the log file:

```
Execution error,return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask
```

`Run time Exception:error` in configuring object.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using serde to load web data into the 1st table it will serialize and deserialize the table data while insert and select. So, in the second table to which you are trying to insert data should also be aware of the serde used.

use the following syntax it might help you.

CREATE TABLE new_table_XX ROW FORMAT SERDE "org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde" AS SELECT   .....